# Loading photo from image control to another image control in excel

Tags: excel, vba, image, activex

I am looking to have one image control with a default image set on my worksheet1.  On all other worksheets I will have numerous other image controls where people can upload photos.  I have a button to delete the photo they would upload but want the default image to show up when clicked.  I have the code that's posted below, but its set to load from outside the file.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\jjvernon\Desktop\Upload.jpg")
End Sub
```

I am hoping all it will take will be to change what's in-between the parentheses.

Thank you,
JJ

Comment: If I follow what you're asking, simply Image2.Picture = Image1.Picture. You will probably want to qualify the Image objects to the relevant sheet(s)

Comment: I have the default image on a separate worksheet so what would I need to add to the code for that to work?

Comment: As I suggested, qualify the image objects to the relevant sheets, eg: Worksheets("Sheet2").Image1.Picture = Worksheets("Sheet1").Image1.Picture

Comment: It might be better to use the image object names rather than "hard-code", eg Worksheets("Sheet2").OLEObjects("Image1").Object.Picture =

Comment: Added the worksheets into the code and its giving me a Syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct sheet names and object names...?

Comment: the object names are good, it worked when I did the initial suggestion Image2.Picture = Image1.Picture by replacing image from another image on same sheet.  It didn't work when I tried putting in Worksheets("Sheet2").Image1.Picture = Worksheets("Sheet1").Image1.Picture

Comment: The different examples I gave you are syntactically correct. In my 2nd & 3rd examples the images on different sheets are both named "Image1", but adapt the names in your code for the names of your images, maybe one of them is named "Image2"

Comment: I think its my sheet names that are causing my issue, one is Store List and other is 1110 Pic.  When I changed them to just be sheet1 and sheet2 it worked.

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out, I replaced one of them with activesheet so I don't have to change the code on my duplicated sheets in the future.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you use simply Sheet1 and Sheet2 those are 'hard-coded' CodeName's, but it should work fine with the string tab names, like Worksheets("Store List")